# Mapping relations

Tags: relations

> Which of the following relations $f\colon \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q} \!\,$ define a mapping? In each case, supply a reason why
>   $f$ is or is not a mapping.

So my understanding is that a mapping is a special relation is which an element $a$ in the set $A$ gives a unique element $b$ in the set $B$. I guess I don't really understand how to determine which relations are mapping and which are not.

An example given in my book: *"Consider $f(\tfrac{p}{q})=p$. We know $\tfrac12=\tfrac24$ but is $f(\tfrac12)=1$ or $2$?. This relation can not be a mapping because it is not well-defined."*.
I don't really understand this: is it saying because there are so many equivalent fractions, the value of $p$ is not well defined? 
So in relation to my homework problem, is it safe to say that the functions are only mapping if they involve both $p$ and $q$ on the right hand side?

### My attempt:

a. $f(\tfrac{p}{q})=\frac{p+1}{p-2}$

Not a mapping because it is not well defined.
$$
\tfrac12=\tfrac24, f(\tfrac12)=\tfrac{2}{-1}, f(\tfrac36)=4
$$

b. $f(\tfrac{p}{q})=\frac{3p}{3q}$

Mapping
$$
\tfrac12=\tfrac24, f(\tfrac12)=\tfrac36=f(\tfrac24)=\tfrac{6}{12}
$$
c. $f(\tfrac{p}{q})=\frac{p+q}{q^2}$

Not a mapping because it is not well defined.
$$
\tfrac12=\tfrac24, f(\tfrac12)=\tfrac34, f(\tfrac24)=\tfrac{6}{16}
$$
d. $f(\tfrac{p}{q})=\frac{3p^2}{7q^2}-\frac{p}{q}$

Mapping
$$
\tfrac12=\tfrac24, f(\tfrac12)=\tfrac{3}{(7\cdot4)}-\tfrac12=-\tfrac{11}{28}, f(\tfrac24)=\tfrac{3\cdot 4}{7\cdot 16}-\tfrac24=-\tfrac{11}{28}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The condition of well-definition of a function is defined as
$$
x = y \implies f(x) = f(y)
$$
and you can note that its inverse implication is $f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$, which is the definition of a 1-1 function. So, to check whether a function is well-defined, in this case, you have to assume
$$
\frac{p}{q} = \frac{p'}{q'}
$$
and verify that their images are the same.